# Creating plots in annotations in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib, I would like to create a plot containing a separate smaller plot within an annotation.  The code I have so far is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.offsetbox import DrawingArea, AnnotationBbox

# Create the main figure and plot something on it
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot([0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,4,9,16])

# Create the secondary plot
fig = Figure()
ax_sub = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax_sub.plot([3,2,1])

# Add the secondary plot axes to a drawing area
da = DrawingArea(250,250)
da.add_artist(ax_sub)

# Add the drawing area to an annotation box
ab = AnnotationBbox(da,[2,10])
ax.add_artist(ab)

# Display
plt.show()
```

which does not quite work - the annotation box is created in the right place, but second plot doesn't get drawn within it.

I know that I can achieve a similar effect by adding new axes to the main plot, but I'd prefer to be able to use an annotation, so that once I get this working I can start using `DraggableAnnotation`s and the like.

Any help would be much appreciated.